Can numerical differentiation be applied to tensor derivatives?
I know that for a 1D function, I can calculate the numerical derivative at every point, $\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d\!} (x_1,y_1)$, with $\d y/\d x$ where $\d y = y_2 - y_0$ and $\d x = x_2 - x_0$. If my step size is small enough, the slope can be approximated as linear.
I know that the derivative of a tensor, say $A$, with dimensions $n\times n$, with respect to another tensor, say $B$, with dimensions $n\times n$, will yield a 4th rank tensor of dimension $n\times n\times n\times n$.
The question is on extending the linear approximation to tensor:
If I just want a rough estimate of the derivative of $A$ with respect to $B$, $\d A/\d B$, is it ok to calculate the components of $\d A/\d B$ following the numerical differentiation formula above? I.e. for $n = 6$, I have:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{\d A}{\d B}(1,1,1,1) = \dfrac{A_2(1,1) - A_1(1,1)}{B_2(1,1) - B_1(1,1)}\\
\dfrac{\d A}{\d B}(1,2,1,1) = \dfrac{A_2(1,2) - A_1(1,2)}{B_2(1,1) - B_1(1,1)}\\
\dfrac{\d A}{\d B}(1,3,1,1) = \dfrac{A_2(1,3) - A_1(1,3)}{B_2(1,1) - B_1(1,1)}
\end{matrix}
$$
... and so on, where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the tensors $A$ at two consecutive time steps.
Thanks in advance!

what does this mean: "dy/dx where dy = y2 - y1 and dx = x2 - x1" ? the discretization of the derivative $dy/dx$ of the function $y(x)$ is $(1/2)[y(x+1)-y(x-1)]$

@CarloBeenakker you are correct. What I was thinking is if my step size is small, every point in the derivative can be approximated as linear, so I am simply calculating a linear slope with that.

In any case, my question is mainly whether if it can be extended to a tensor like that

a tensor is just an array of functions, I really do not understand the question.

It sounds like you agree that the derivative tensor components can indeed be extended from a simple y = f(x) case since it is just an array of functions?

certainly, you just have many functions that depend on many parameters, "tensor" for your purpose is just a word to arrange these functions into an array, you might as well arrange them in a single string.

Ok thank you. My numerical estimate is way different from the analytical counter-part, and more likely to be wrong. I was expecting the numerical estimate to be closer to the correct answer. The issue I am having is either a linear approximation is not good enough, or the quantities are wrong then.

Interesting question. I am looking answers about accuracy, any existing implementations doing this calculation in matlab/python. Running a for loop for the array of function might look unrealistics for large scale implementation. What will be the choice of step size, e.g. it should be a uniform for all components or should it be an array of step sizes which would affect accuracy?
I need this for applications in continuum mechanics like energy derivatives, derivative of second order with second order.

I understand that one may want to differentiate a tensor numerically in a certain direction. Why is differentiating a tensor with respect to another tensor of the same dimensions, the way you defined it, natural? What is the motivation?

I expect the derivative of a tensor of dimensions $n$ by $n$ to be a tensor of dimensions $n$ by $n$ by $n$. Then, if you want a derivative of the original tensor in a certain direction $v$, you just contract $v$ with the first index of the derivative. There are issues with how to define this on a curved space, i.e. a manifold, but this is resolved using connections. I may be misunderstanding your question, in which case I apologize.
